# Graph api - individual stories while posting images

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this code to post pictures to a FB wall. But when I post like 4 or more pictures, the story collapses together and shows "(page name) added 4 photos to album ..." ... Is there a way to achieve individual story for each picture?

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
  array(
    'access_token' => $token,
    'message' => $mes,
    'url' => $img
  )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
  )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos', false, $context);
```

Comment: There are individual stories for each photo. Facebook just collapses them into a single story on most user's newsfeeds. No, there isn't any way to force these to show the full story for each picture.

Comment: Well, if you post it manually clicking the "Post photo / video" link on the page, it appears individually... But you say there is no way for the graph api, right?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it by uploading the photo with no story, and then sharing it. You can share as many pictures as you want but it will remain single posts.

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
  array(
    'access_token' => $token,
    'message' => $mes,
    'url' => $img,
    'no_story' => '1'
  )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
  )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$album_id.'/photos', false, $context));

$postdata = http_build_query(
  array(
    'access_token' => $token,
    'is_hidden' => 'true'
  )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
  )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result2 = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$result->id, false, $context);

$postdata = http_build_query(
  array(
    'access_token' => $token,
    'link' => 'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid='.$result->id
  )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
  )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result3 = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$id.'/feed', false, $context);
```